# Starbucks integration with Java based web app

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, jakarta-ee

We want to integrate starbucks gift card option in our application, but we are unable to find any starbucks developer support api online. Kindly help us as soon as possible.Thanks in advance for your help.

This functionality is already available on facebook for US based users.

Answer (score 0):

Starbucks may not have opened up any APIs for world. Found this interesting API while searching on internet, not sure how reliable/robust this API is:

http://jonathanstark.com/card/#api

Comment: Then how is facebook is able to use starbucks? Is it some kind of proprietary integration? And I have already checked out this link. It doesn't serve the purpose.

Comment: may be its proprietary integration and is not public. or may be some partnership b/w starbucks and FB.

Answer (score 0):

ever checked out tangocard api? it includes the starbucks gift card api... http://cm.gy/9ixo